# Getting a subset efficiently when non-seekable

Tags: php, arrays, loops, iteration, slice

I have a fairly large array that I have structured as such: http://pastebin.com/EQjerbcE I am trying to find a more efficient way of taking out a subset/slice of this array. Currently I am doing this:

```
$valToken = $attrSizes[$array->Size];   //14

$sizeNames = [];
foreach ($attrSizes AS $key => $value)
{
    if ($valToken === $value)
    {
        $sizeNames[] = $key;
    }

    if ($valToken < $value) break;
}
```

In my opinion though, looping should not be the answer as it is fairly inefficient. I did though add a clause to break after the `$valToken` is less than the `$value` to make sure I do NOT run a full loop if not needed. There must be a smarter, more efficient way of doing this though with all the array methods that we have available in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$sizeNames = array_keys($attrSizes, $array->Size, true);
```

By the way: I would structure the array like that:

```
$attrSizes = [
        0 => ['*NONE', ],
        1 => ['XS (101)', 'S (102)', 'M (103)', 'L (104)', 'XL (105)', 'XXL (106)', 'XXXL (107)', ],
        2 => ['Small x 31 (110)', 'Small x 33 (111)', ...],
        ...
];
```

Comment: Throws undefined index, this does look like it could be the answer though or returns empty

Comment: It is working (w/ your pastebin array) here. Your `$attrSizes` and `$array->Size`are set?

Comment: Yep issue on my end, I just caught it ;) Thanks! +1 and accepted Sir

Comment: Good idea on your comment, I'll swap the arrary structure